# Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\vishw\AnewProject\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\vishw\.gradle\caches\6.8\

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

[image]iam trying to run the gradlew in the react-native project which is required for firebase phone authentication and iam getting the error